# Phone replacement parts: original vs copy

Tags: integrated-circuit, mobile, mobile-phones

I'm looking to buy a replacement micro USB board for my Xiaomi Redmi 6. As your can note for example on this [product page](https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/32824133336.html), there exist "original" and "copy" versions for the same component.

The "copy" has a lot less components than the "original" one. So I'm wondering, how could they achieve the same functionality with that much less components?

[image: copy]
[image: original]

Comment: Look up Muntzing. In this case it looks like it might be some IC responsible for charge management or interfacing with the USB-C.

Comment: Note the board is also in charge of the microphone and the antenna. I'd say the "copy" model does a worse job at managing the charging current, the microphone sound quality, the antenna signal, and so on. But I really can't say for sure.

Comment: For the record, I'm just ordering both versions. So that for the time I'll have to replace the (real) original connector, I'll just try the Chinese "original" version first, and keep at hand the "copy" version as a backup.